# How do I allow Cross-Origin Requests from greasemonkey scripts in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, cross-domain, localhost

I'm developing a Greasemonkey script that implements a couple of tools onto a webpage. This script makes a request for data from

```
http://localhost/chess/heartbeat.php
```

Now currently in Firefox I am getting this console error which totally stops my jQuery AJAX request for data.

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at

```
http://localhost/chess/heartbeat.php.
```

> This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.

I am able to work around this using Google Chrome. When I have it as a simple browser extension for chrome, I'm able to have it do the same thing as Greasemonkey and I can add the following permissions to the manifest file for the plugin which allows me to make the same data request which Firefox blocked:

```
"permissions": [
    "<all_urls>"
  ]
```

Anyway, this works on chrome, but I want to achieve the same effect on Firefox. I've been researching this issue and I can't find a simple answer.

Comment: http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_xmlhttpRequest

Answer (score 15):

Normally `XMLHttpRquest`, and that includes jQuery's higher-level API around it, does not allow unrestricted cross-site requests but is limited by the same-origin policy and [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

As @epascarello already pointed out, you may use [`GM.xmlHttpRequest`](https://wiki.greasespot.net/GM.xmlHttpRequest) which allows you to perform any cross-site XHR even when the server does not implement CORS or allows the origin site. It also comes with some other goodies.

You should add a [`@grant GM.xmlHttpRequest`](http://wiki.greasespot.net/@grant) metadata block to your user script or your script may break in the future.

Since you mentioned Chrome extensions: Firefox extensions can perform cross-site XHR as well. e.g. most user scripts should be easily portable to an SDK add-on using [`PageMod`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/page-mod.html) and enabling [certain permissions](https://web.archive.org/web/20150919105344/https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/Cross_Domain_Content_Scripts) analog to what you'd do in a Chrome extension.

Comment: if only there was a cross browser method for doing this that would work on scripts and extensions, it would make things a lot easier.

Comment: They only perform the XHR from the extension scope, not the pages scope, making this rather difficult.