# I receive a 404 HTTP error with an API using javascript but not in my terminal

Tags: javascript, http, http-headers, http-status-code-404

I am using the Pons dictionary API documented here: https://en.pons.com/assets/docs/api_dict.pdf.
It works when I use a get request in my Mac terminal, but not when using `XMLHttpRequest` in my JavaScript file (shown below) when testing it in my browser. It always gives me a 404 error and then states:

> "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.pons.com/v1/dictionary?q=casa&l=dees' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status."

Any ideas?

I have tried making a request that does not require my X-Secret (credentials) and it works, but as soon as I set the X-Secret header it throws a 404 error. I need to set this heading for most request types.
Here is my code. I have censored my credentials in the X-Secret header.

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest()

let url = new URL('https://api.pons.com/v1/dictionary');
url.searchParams.set('q', 'casa');
url.searchParams.set('l', 'dees');

request.open('GET', url);
//request.withCredentials = true;
request.setRequestHeader("X-Secret", "***");
request.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
request.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
request.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT");
request.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Authorization");
request.send()

request.onload = function() {
  // Begin accessing JSON data here
  var data = JSON.parse(this.response)
  if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
    console.log(data)
  } else {
    console.log('error')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CORS is "cross-origin resource sharing"; specifically, it's used to refer to policies that block requests between different domains. In this case, XHR is sending a "preflight request" -- that is, a request with verb OPTIONS (rather than GET, POST, etc.) -- to make sure the server will accept a real request. It will do this whenever you use non-standard (and some standard but optional) headers. The preflight request is coming back as 404; the server doesn't support OPTIONS to that endpoint.

The way to get around CORS is to use a proxy. That is, have a backend script (in Node, PHP, whatever) on your domain that sends the request to the other API server and echoes its response. CORS only applies to AJAX requests, not backend ones, so this will get around the issue, and it is the accepted technique.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I am trying to use this API within a user script. Is it possible to do what you described for this purpose?

Comment: This might be useful information for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24688294/how-do-i-allow-cross-origin-requests-from-greasemonkey-scripts-in-firefox

Comment: Oh, you're awesome! This worked for me. Thanks a ton.